# Execution of the code is not top to bottom

Tags: javascript, node.js

The execution order does not seem to be correct or I'm missing something.

This is the code:

```
function main() {
    helper.openRS()
    console.log("START")
    let hexColorsArray = helper.readColorData()
    let startX = 0
    let startY = 627
    let areaX, areaY = 100
    let found = false

    console.log(itemData.grotworm.colors)

    while(!found) {
        colorFound = helper.findColor(startX,startY,areaX,areaY, hexColorsArray)

        console.log("StartX: " + startX + ", StartY: " + startY)
        if(colorFound.state) {
            found = true
            console.log("Color Found?: " + colorFound.state)
            robot.moveMouse(colorFound.random_x, colorFound.random_y)
            robot.mouseClick()
        } else {
            if (startX + 100 >= 1920) {
                startX = 263
                startY -= 100
            } else if (startY < 5) {
                found = true
            } else {
                startX += 100
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**findColor**

```
function findColor(x,y,width,height, colors) {
    let img = robot.screen.capture(x, y, width, height);
    let test = width * height
    let random_x = 0
    let random_y = 0
    let color = []

    for (let i = 0; i < test; i++) {
        random_x = getRandomInt(0, width-1);
        random_y = getRandomInt(0, height-1);
        color = img.colorAt(random_x, random_y)
        console.log("COLOR: " + color)
        if (colors.includes(color)) {
            return {"random_x": random_x + x,"random_y": random_y + y,"state": true};
        }
    }
    
    return {"random_x": 0, "random_y": 0,"state": false}
}
```

The intention of this code is to read json file of colors in hex and assign it to hexColorsArray, iterate through 100x100 images on the screen and trying to find the correct pixel color in that image, if the color is found the image exits. However the issue I'm having is that the console.log("COLOR: " + color) in the **function findColor()** prints before anything else.

Head of the output:

```
$ npm start

> test@1.0.0 start
> node main.js

COLOR: 202020
COLOR: d8eafa
COLOR: 202020
COLOR: 202020
COLOR: 202020
COLOR: 202020
COLOR: ffd253
COLOR: 202020
COLOR: 202020
COLOR: 202020
COLOR: 202020
COLOR: 202020
COLOR: 202020
COLOR: 202020
COLOR: 202020
COLOR: 202020
COLOR: e9e9e9
```

Comment: Where is `main()` called? And is `findColor()` only called from `main()` or from other locations as welll? What is `helper.openRS()` doing? There is literally *no way*  that in a call of `main()` the output from within `findColor()` comes before the output of `START` (unless of course, some execution path in `openRS` somehow also calls `findColor()`

Comment: You are completely correct, thanks. Totally forgot that openRS also calls findColor().